# Is it different between Puppeteer's evaluate and Chrome DevTools(headed)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I scrape a site with Puppeteer.
The code like this:

```js
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr'));

  let results = [];
  trs.forEach(tr => {
    let r = {};

    r["cell"] = tr.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)')[0].innerText;

    const input = tr.querySelectorAll('input[name="number"]');
    if (input.length > 0) {
      r["number"] = input[0].value;
    }

    results.push(r);
  });

  return results;
});
```

I hope I can get "data" like this:
* In fact, This is Chrome DevTools' result.

```
[
  {cell: "a", input: "b"},
  {cell: "c", input: "d"}
]
```

But When I run it with Puppeteer, The result is:

```
[
  {cell: "a"},
  {cell: "c"}
]
```

Is it different between them? or the other else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the exact answer.
However, it looks like it can't scrape value from selector `'input[name="number"]'`.
I rewrite it with `'input[type="hidden"]'`, it can works.